# Twitter Error - {"errors":[{"code":53,"message":"Basic authentication is not supported"}]}

Tags: php, twitter

I have noticed when a user has ran out of API request I am seeing:

> {"errors":[{"code":53,"message":"Basic authentication is not supported"}]}

Is there a way in PHP I can output this?

Comment: This is a json response. Are you asking how to out put a json resposne in php?

Comment: I want to know how to just get the code part of the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll find that twitter has turned off basic authentication. You will have to use OAuth from now on.

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq

Answer (score 2):

```
$myarray = json_decode($error_string, true);
$code = $myarray['errors'][0]['code'];
```